# Inverse model problem

Tags: geochemistry, models, inversion

I have a dataset for river water, rain water and geology (main elements and trace elements). I want to apportion the contribution of geology to water chemistry using for that purpose a model. I was trying to use the Inverse model approach (Tarantola, 2005) but no clear definition is provided in the bibliographic sources (Gaillardet et al, 1999; Millot et al, 2003; Wu et al, 2005, Moon et al, 2007).

Any ideas of how to apportion the river elements into different sources (reservoirs) and derive weathering rates as function of the geology (mainly igneous rocks: andesite and some rhyolites, eventually some carbonates) with the described information?

Comment: Do you have any strontium isotopic data. That can be helpful in interpreting different geologic sources. Perhaps not quite what you are looking for but you might want to check out doi:10.5194/bg-11-4099-2014

Comment: I have strontium, but not the isotopic composition. And also I have some clues about the potential sources but I need to prove it.